# merge multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I have an array like :
using for each loop I am getting these two arrays

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [Easycase] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6119
                [uniq_id] => 94e163c35e99944b30a452a2220cbc3f
                [case_no] =>1
                [title] => Task 1
                [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                [due_date] => 2015-01-29

            )

    )

)
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Easycase] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6121
                    [uniq_id] => b1825674988deb63e0ee7204d6ab0d9a
                    [case_no] => 2

                    [title] => Task 2
                    [assign_to] => 878
                    [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                    [due_date] => 2015-01-29
                )
```

```
    )

)
```

I want to convert this array which looks like below

`Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Milestone 1
        [series] => Array
            (
               [0]=>Array(
                  [id] => 6119
                [name] => Task 2
                [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                [due_date] => 2015-01-29
              )
              [1]=>Array(
                 [id]=>6121
                 [name] => Task 1
                [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                [due_date] => 2015-01-29
            )

    )`

)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below function to format the inner array:

```
$easycase = Set::classicExtract($easycase, '{n}.User');

This will return array with below format

 Array
        (
            [0]=>Array(
                [id] => 6119
                [uniq_id] => 94e163c35e99944b30a452a2220cbc3f
                [case_no] =>1
                [title] => Task 1
                [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                [due_date] => 2015-01-29
            )
          [1]=>Array(
                [id] => 6121
                [uniq_id] => b1825674988deb63e0ee7204d6ab0d9a
                [case_no] => 2

                [title] => Task 2
                [assign_to] => 878
                [gantt_start_date] => 2015-01-26
                [due_date] => 2015-01-29
          )
       )
```